# How is the Borjgali related to Mesopotamian symbols of eternity?

Tags: mesopotamia, symbolism

The Borjgali is a Georgian solar symbol:

> Borjgali (Georgian: ბორჯღალი; also Borjgala or Borjgalo) is a Georgian symbol of the Sun with seven rotating wings over the Christian Tree of Life and is related to the Mesopotamian symbols of eternity.
>
> [image: Borjgali]
>
> <sub>Source: Borjgali, https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Borjgali&oldid=676638846 (last visited Jan. 30, 2016).</sub>

Unfortunately, the claim that the symbol is somehow related to Mesopotamian symbols of eternity is unsourced. One eternity symbol that is broadly similar to the Borjgali is [that of neighboring Armenia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armenian_eternity_sign). However, Armenia is not a Mesopotamian culture.

How is the Borjgali related to Mesopotamian symbols of eternity? And which symbols might those be?

Comment: This is based on [a question](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/58307/mythology/67604#67604) from the site's Area51 definition phase.

Answer (score 1):

Mesopotamian sign of Eternity is same as Georgian Borjgali, Georgians also speak language which is derived from Shumer and Mesopotamia since survivors of "the great deluge" settled in Caucasus mountains and brought the language and culture from there, also known as Caucasian (see Caucasian particularly Kartvelian languages) later Antiochian Christians from Rome changed it to sign of Sun.

Armenian is not Mesopotamian culture and their language is not considered as such (Caucasian), but they have been inhabiting Caucasian mountains since 590BC during the time of "Yervanduri" when Kingdom of Urartu fell and new nation and people were established which westerners called "Armina", thus Armenians have continued Caucasian tradition from Urartu and Kingdom of Nairi and their relatives (Kartvelians)

in short Georgians (Kartvelians) are the closest people of culture of Shumer and Mesopotamia and have preserved culture, symbols and language derived from there, but it's very important that we remember and understand that this is a sign of ETERNITY, NOT SYMBOL OF SUN.

it is symbol that portrays cycles of life and universe and ages, simply put it says "what was once will be again".

Comment: Sorry, but you are incorrect, "shumer" or "shumeruli" is Georgian Caucasian way of saying Sumer and Sumerian...connection is undeniable, Georgian is western new name given to Caucasian tribal people, but the real name is "sakartvelo" which means "land of people of Kartlos"...Kartlos was related to Noah who settled in mountains and brought the language derived from Babylon, Sumer and Mesopotamia,..Kartvelian people are just tribal Caucasian people who have preserved Mesopotamian language and culture after "the great deluge"

Comment: Georgians are the only ones who speak Language derived from Sumer  known as Asomtavruli http://svanetifood.blogspot.com/2011/10/svaneti.html   connection is undeniable, sorry, Sumerians are not Black they are from Mesopotamia not Africa, I know this "everyone is black" is trendy to some people, but it's not factual or reality, Svans are one of the Georgian (Kartvelian) tribes and connection is crystal clear, Kartvelians have preserved culture, language, symbols and even many names derived from Sumer, even the names of villages bear resemblance, so again sorry this is reality we like it or not.

Comment: Svans are the highest mountain people of Georgia  "Scientists rightly believe that this old Georgian tribe displays affinity with ancient Sumerians. Suffice to recall some names: Enilile - Sumerian Sun god, Lakhamu - the Sumerian god of the underworld waters. Two villages in Svaneti bear this name. Lakhamu's mother is "Igi" - the earth, "Gim" in Svanetian. Unwritten annals of the Svans have been leafed through for 7 thousands years. It should be a miracle that they have survived to this day - in the form of a myth, a logos, a song"

Comment: much of the science behind this is still uncovering evidence, but since we have hit the information age and rapidly are moving in to golden age, everything will be put to light, there is a reason why Borjghali is is the national symbol, and there is a reason for why Asomtavruli is also the basis of Georgian language which has been added to cultural heritages of humanity, so yes, the names, language and symbols of national heritage does matter, at least to scientists and historians.